# Flutter - Show alert dialog after StreamBuilder loaded data and UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, rxdart, stream-builder

I want to show an alert dialog after I get data from StreamBuilder. I also have a UI to render. Currently, I'm having an error like this when I'm trying to build dialog inside `_loadUI` method before returning actual UI.

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Code:

```
if (dataSnapshot.hasData) {
            return dataSnapshot.data ? _loadUI(dataSnapshot.data) : _emptyView();
          }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this:

```dart
void _loadUI(snapshot) {
...

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      ...
    );
  });
}
```

addPostFrameCallback run during a frame, just after the persistent frame callbacks (which is when the main rendering pipeline has been flushed).

Comment: Hey, I'm able to show the dialog now but it's rendering every time I resume screen. Or navigate to any other screen.

Comment: are you sure you didn't use `addPersistentFrameCallback`?

Comment: No, I did use the answered one. Figured it's the issue with build method calling every time inside StreamBuilder but that's another issue. Thanks for your help mate.
Also, do you have any reference link for that issue?